# pyLucene Installation

Tags: python, lucene, pylucene

I am on Ubuntu 10.04, Python 2.6.5 & having some trouble installing pyLucene.

Here's what I have done so far, installed these packages -

```
sudo apt-get install ant
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk
sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-1.5.0-sun
sudo apt-get install gcc
sudo apt-get install g++
sudo apt-get install gcj
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

After that got the source code of pyLucene from http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/lucene/pylucene/. I got version pylucene-3.0.1-1.

Untared it. Since JCC needs to be built first; went to JCC dir & then typed `python setup.py install`. got an error about some setuptools patch. it told me to do this - 
`sudo patch -d /usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages -Nup0 < /home/code/python/lucene/pylucene-3.0.1-1/jcc/jcc/patches/patch.43.0.6c11`

and I did. but I got this on the terminal -

```
patching file setuptools/extension.py
patching file setuptools/command/build_ext.py
Hunk #1 FAILED at 85.
Hunk #2 succeeded at 177 (offset 7 lines).
Hunk #3 succeeded at 259 (offset 7 lines).
1 out of 3 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file setuptools/command/build_ext.py.rej
```

Now my build fails - i.e. when I do `sudo python setup.py build` I get -

```
...
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version do you need? There's a PPA with 2.9.2-1 here:

https://launchpad.net/~owenmorris/+archive/ppa

Comment: as mentioned in the question - @inception has used the version of pylucene 3.0.1

Comment: @MovieYoda: The version he's tried might not be the version he *needs*.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem may be that the patch is for setuptools 0.6-11 and you have an earlier version of setuptools (prob 0.6-10) installed from your distro's packages.

I have had a similar problem that was resolved by removing the version of setuptools installed by the distro and installing your own downloaded from http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools

I have had no problems yet, but there is a very small chance that this will interfere with some other programs on your system.

Comment: I think this may be wrong! I think with the newer setuptools you don't need the patch at all.

Comment: or none of the above and install JCC direct from your package manager

Comment: Actually you do need the patch, even with version 0.6.11c