# Pylucene installation on MacOs with adoptopenjdk / Java8

Tags: python, macos, java-8, pylucene, jcc

I am trying to install JCC (as part of the installation of PyLucene) and I encountered several issues with it.
The python version I use is 3.7, and I have installed adoptopenjdk-8.jdk using brew cask (since Java-8 is no longer available without specific license (read it somewhere)). After this didn't really worked I manually installed Java-8

The error I am receiving while trying to run setup.py in shell (using either java8 or adoptopenjdk) is:

```
OSError: warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 5 
error: Source option 5 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later. 
error: Target option 5 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later.
```

Please help me install PyLucene!

It is related to these (but they are outdated and doesn't work):

[pyLucene Installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438936/pylucene-installation)

https://medium.com/@michaelaalcorn/how-to-use-pylucene-e2e2f540024c

**EDIT:**
I realized this is related to javac versions but idk how to solve it.
This site looks helpful (from the code) but I can't understand whats written here:  https://www.jianshu.com/p/dcd149a65eb0

Comment: Hi, please refer to our help center when asking questions, especially [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) section. This question will probably get more attention on [super user](https://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So,

Changing the the setup.py file in 2 locations solved it:

line 185:

```
JAVAC = {
'darwin': ['/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_221.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/javac', '-source', '1.5', '-target', '1.5'],
```

and adding one line here (line 68):

```
JAVAHOME = '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_221.jdk/Contents/Home'

JDK = {
'darwin': JAVAHOME,
'ipod': '/usr/include/gcc',
```

Answer (score 0):

After much gnashing of teeth, I found that this works to build pylucene

My configuration:

- Mac OSX 10.15.7
- Powerbook Intel core i7  (I note this, because I got
  the weird error "gcc: error: this compiler does not support arm64"
  when trying to compile with gcc)
- Python 2.7.16 (Python 3.8.2 doesn't seem to work... lots of compile
  errors with bad types.)
- Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)
- gcc (Homebrew GCC 10.2.0_3) 10.2.0

I used clang instead of gcc (which doesn't seem to work at all) by doing this:

```
export CC=/usr/bin/clang
export CXX=/usr/bin/clang++
```

In the file setup.py, I removed `-ljava` and `-ljvm` flags from the LFLAG dictionary where darwin is in the key.  Otherwise, ld complains.

I've managed only to build pylucene.  I have no idea (yet) whether it will work with Python 2.7 or Python 3.x

I will update with details.